# Creating a user and adding public key on aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I've created a user and copied the public key to `.ssh/authorized_key` for that new user and also I've set the `pubkeyauthentication` to yes on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` after saving the file restarted the sshd service.

When I try to ssh from the new user I am getting error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Am I missing any step here to ssh from the new user account?

When I check the status for sshd.servive I see  error:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys xxxx SHA256:84NyibLXFppE4BGIM+1e5iO...status 22
```

Comment: Did you update permissions on file and folder? Folder should be 700 and authorized_key should be 600

Comment: Yes, I've set permission 700 to .ssh directory and 600 to authorized_key file.

Comment: The filename should be `authorized_keys` (plural).

Comment: yes, I've created the file in plural.

Comment: I think the server-side error you quoted may be unrelated, and caused by https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-config/issues/20.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue `error: AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys ec2-user`.

Make sure the file permission is user only (600) in the $HOME/.ssh directory on the SSH client side host.

- ["error: AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys ...snip... failed, status 22" error #20](https://github.com/aws/aws-ec2-instance-connect-config/issues/20)

## FYI

To debug:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/secure` to monitor the reason why SSH refuses the connection.

Make sure $HOME/.ssh/authorized_key content on EC2 instance is correctly match with your ssh private key in the SSH client host.

Make sure correct private key is being used, use `-i` option to explicitly specify which key you use.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the algorithm you are using to generate the key.

I saw exactly the same error message when using the ECDSA algorithm but fixed the problem by using RSA instead (ssh-keygen -t rsa).

If you want to dig deeper you can try

```
ssh -Q key
```

to get a list of supported key types.